# access my app engine endpoint from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How do I access my own app-engine endpoint from javascript? Any short example? I am working on an android app and add AppEngine to it as a module. Now I want to add a web-client. How do I access my AppEngine server from javascript?

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/calling-from-javascript) for using the Endpoints frameworks from JavaScript.